# Replacing embedded data with a URL in Python

Tags: python, url, flask

I have this working Python code.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

    app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'Public',
        'description': 'Available to download',
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': 'Non-Public',
        'description': 'Not available to download',
        'done': False
    },
     {
        'id': 3,
        'title': 'Restricted-Public',
        'description': 'got to',
        'done': False
    }
]

@app.route('/api/PDL/<int:task_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_task(task_id):
    task = [task for task in tasks if task['id'] == task_id]
    if len(task) == 0:
        abort(404)
    return jsonify({'task': task[0]})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am trying to replace the following to read from an external data.json:

```
tasks = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'title': 'Public',
            'description': 'Available to download',
            'done': False
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'title': 'Non-Public',
            'description': 'Not available to download',
            'done': False
        },
         {
            'id': 3,
            'title': 'Restricted-Public',
            'description': 'got to',
            'done': False
        }
    ]
```

I tried using `tasks = open("/myproject/test.json")`, but I get the following Python error.

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what it is you want to do?

Comment: @Niels I am trying to replace the data i have in the code with a link to a larger Json file. It will be more convienent to me to update the Json file than updating the data in my script

Comment: which data are you trying to replace, and how did you try to do this? It is not really clear to me how your code is supposed to be used.

Comment: @Niels I am trying to replace the data for 'tasks'. When the script is activated I am able to pass parameters in the URL to get data. For example I can type /api/PDL/1 in the URL and get the JSON record for id=1. the data in production is in JSON format and is large (over 1000 records). I was thinking about linking to the json file instead of listing the records within my script

Comment: I'm mainly asking this to get it clear what your exact problem is, so others can try to help you. If you edit your question with a better description of the problem you have higher odds that someone can help you. So you say you have code to pick out a certain task from your json. That still does not describe how you want to change your task. (and is it the description or title that you want to change into an url?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the file with `open`, you're reading the contents as a **string** into `tasts`. You need to convert to a Python `dictionary` object in order to be able use it as you are in your previous code.

Try [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). To set the proper string in the file to start, do:

```
import json

tasks = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'Public',
        'description': 'Available to download', 
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': 'Non-Public',
        'description': 'Not available to download', 
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'title': 'Restricted-Public',
        'description': 'got to', 
        'done': False
    }
]

with open('/myproject/test.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(tasks))
```

Then, to load the contents of the file as a Python `dictionary`:

```
import json

with open('/myproject/test.json') as f:
    tasks = json.loads(f.read())
```